# SOQL Query returning 0 Rows

Tags: soql

The query
[SELECT Id FROM Contact]

is returning zero rows in a test class.
I have tried everything I can think of. Why won't it return all records?

When I run the test I am seeing this line in the log.
SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN [4]|Aggregations:0|SELECT Id FROM Contact
SOQL_EXECUTE_END   [4]|Rows:0

Answer (score 2):

By default, test methods cannot see your data.

You can override this using

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
```

at the top of your test class, but best practice is to build the test records in the class, insert them, and then use those for the test. The data will automatically roll back so you don't need to worry about deleting the records.

The reason you want to do it that way is so that your test methods are fully portable without relying on org data. That way if you create a developer sandbox, newly refreshed without any data, the tests will still pass because they are creating and testing their own records.

Tests, of course, don't have to pass in Sandbox environments, but a good test is used as a sort of coal-mine canary, and it is very useful to be able to know if any new code or configuration changes you have made in your sandbox environment break existing functionality before spending the time to deploy it to production. If you deploy to Production and have it fail there where you have to go back, make changes, re-package your deployment, and try all over again. This is time consuming and wasteful.

Also worth mentioning is that you should always write your tests to actually validate the intended functionality of your applications. Salesforce does enforce the 75% code coverage minimum in Production environments, so you are going to spend time writing tests no matter what, and you might as well write good ones. Good tests will help alert you to your own mistakes, and tests that cover your app functionality will almost always also result in a higher code coverage percentage than what SFDC requires. If you are using your tests to validate your app logic, them passing or failing becomes valuable feedback, providing early warnings of bugs when they fail and affirming good functionality when they pass.

Comment: I am afraid that your reason for not using `SeeAllData` is not strong enough and could cause readers to think that it is not worth the trouble since having test pass in a sandbox or DE is irrelevant because they do not need to pass. Could you rephrase your conclusion to be something more relevant to a production instance?

Comment: I expanded my answer to explain the justification in my reasoning that best practice is to have tests that do pass in your Sandbox / development environment. Thanks!